# Understanding the isomorphism between tangent spaces and derivations

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, tangent-spaces

I have a problem with the last line of the following proof that shows that tangent space $T_p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is isomorphic to the space of derivations at point $p$, $\mathcal{D}_p(\mathbb{R}^n)$:
[image]
[image]

I fail to understand the last line which shows surjectivity. How does it follow from $D = D_v$, with $ v=\langle Dx^1, Dx^2, \ldots, Dx^n\rangle$.

**Edit:**
$D_v$ is the directional derivative and derivations are defined in terms of their action on products of $C^\infty$ functions $f, g$.
$$
D(fg)(p) = (Df)g(p)+(Dg)f(p)
$$

Comment: Just try to apply $D_v$, with that choice of $v$, to the germ $f$ and you see that $$ D_vf(x) = \sum_iv^i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}(x) = \sum_i(Dx^i)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}(x) = Df(x)$$ and then conclude by arbitrarily of $f$ that $D_v = D$, i.e. the mapping is surjective.